# Trying to copy the nth file in a directory to another folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to generate a random number and then use that random number to grab the corresponding file in the directory, this will in turn create a random playlist of music songs. I take 3 arguments , the path to your music, the name of the new playlist, and how many songs you want in that playlist. For some reason at each iteration of the while loop it copies multiple files instead of just that nth random file

```
#!/bin/bash

#accepts 3 arguments path to music, name of the new playlist, and amount of songs you want in         the playlist
path_to_music=$1;
playlistname=$2;
count=$3;

#finds number of songs in directory, allows for more effective randomness


#cd to the path where music is  
if [ -d "$path_to_music" ];
then
    eval cd $path_to_music
    numOfFiles=$(find . -type f | wc -l)
else
    echo "Directory does not exist, enter correct path."
    read path_to_file
fi

ran=$[ ( $RANDOM % 5 )  + 1 ]
let ran=numOfFiles-ran;
#make new folder where music is, will contain random songs (new playlist)
mkdir $playlistname

i=1
while : #while loop finds a random song and copies it to folder created, $cnt is randomly generated so songs are random
do  
    if [ "$i" -ne "$count" ];
    then    
        cnt=$[ ( $RANDOM %  34)  + 1 ]  
        let "cnt*=(-1)" 
        find -type f | head $cnt tail $cnt | xargs -I % cp % $path_to_music/$playlistname ;
        let "i+=1"
        echo $i
    else
        break;
    fi
done;
```

Comment: `head $cnt tail $cnt` is missing a `|` in between. `eval cd $path_to_music` is *evil*. Just drop the `eval`, quote the variable and live with `~` not working.

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
printf '%s\n' * | shuf | head -1 | xargs -I% cp % /another/dir/%
```

Comment: Or even `cp $(printf '%s\n' * | shuf -n 1) /another/dir/.`, to eliminate a couple extra unnecessary steps...

Answer (score 0):

The command `head $cnt tail $cnt` is malformed; you meant `head $cnt | tail -1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use    head -n|tail -1

n is the nth

try to print: printf '%s\n' * | printf '%s\n' * | head -4 | tail -1, so it first select the first 4 files, and then use tail -1 to choose the last one from these 4 files, so the 4th on is chosen